# Add some way to specify indeterminate checkboxes in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Add some way to specify indeterminate checkboxes in blazor.

I have tried below code, but it did not work.

`<input type="checkbox" indeterminate="@checkValue" onclick="@checkedClick" />`

How can I specify indeterminate checkboxes in blazor?

Comment: HTML does not do indeterminate checkboxes. You will need some CSS trickery.

Comment: You have to set the property with Javascript.  Luckily, using Javascript Interop, this should be trivially easy to do: https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 5):

I seems this is not planned for a while. (see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10378)

The minimal solution I have found is this ...

Component code

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<input @ref=inputElement type="checkbox" checked="@Checked" @onchange="OnChange" />

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (Indeterminate.HasValue)
        {
            await jsRuntime.SetElementProperty(inputElement, "indeterminate", Indeterminate.Value);
        }
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private ElementReference inputElement;

    [Parameter]
    public bool? Indeterminate { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> CheckedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Checked = (bool)e.Value;
        await CheckedChanged.InvokeAsync(Checked);
    }
}
```

Interop C# code

```
public static async Task SetElementProperty(this IJSRuntime jsRuntime, ElementReference element, string property, object value)
{
    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window.jsinterop.setPropByElement", element, property, value);
}
```

Interop Javascript code

```
window.jsinterop = {
    setPropByElement: function (element, property, value) {
        element[property] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63121649/558211) got me started but didn't fully work for me, this did:

IndeterminateCheckbox.razor :

```html
<input @ref="_inputElement" type="checkbox" checked="@Checked" @onchange="OnChange" />
```

IndeterminateCheckbox.razor.cs :

```cs
public partial class IndeterminateCheckbox
{
    private ElementReference _inputElement;
    private bool _indeterminate;
    private protected bool Checked { get; private set; }
    private CheckState CheckState { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    private JavaScriptHelper JavaScript { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public CheckState StartCheckState { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<CheckState> CheckedChanged { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (StartCheckState is CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
            _indeterminate = true;
            Checked = false;
            CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
        }
        else if (StartCheckState is CheckState.Checked)
        {
            Checked = true;
            CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }
        await CheckedChanged.InvokeAsync(CheckState);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JavaScript.SetElementProperty(_inputElement, "indeterminate", CheckState is CheckState.Indeterminate);
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var indeterminate = !Checked && !_indeterminate;
        var isChecked = !Checked && _indeterminate;
        _indeterminate = indeterminate;
        Checked = isChecked;

        CheckState = indeterminate switch
        {
            false when !isChecked => CheckState.Unchecked,
            false when isChecked => CheckState.Checked,
            _ => CheckState.Indeterminate
        };

        await CheckedChanged.InvokeAsync(CheckState);
    }
}

public enum CheckState
{
    Indeterminate,
    Checked,
    Unchecked
}
```

Interop C# code:

```cs
public class JavaScriptHelper
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public JavaScriptHelper(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public async Task SetElementProperty(ElementReference element, string property, object value)
    {
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Functions.setPropByElement", element, property, value);
    }
}
```

And Javascript code:

```js
var Functions = {
    "setPropByElement": function (element, property, value) {
        element[property] = value;
    }
};
```

And use it like so:

```html
<IndeterminateCheckbox StartCheckState="CheckState.Unchecked" CheckedChanged="OnEnabledFilterChange" />
```

If you leave out the parameter then the first of CheckState will be chosen (i.e., `Indeterminate`)

I'm sure there are some improvements to be made so please let me know if so.